# Using the Return Value of a Method in an If Statement

Tags: java

so I'm a newish Java programmer, and this might just be a concept that went right over my head. but if I am calling a boolean method in a program, such as keepDice2 below, how can I check the return value-true of false- in an if statement? Below is my attempt.

I am attempting to make a method, keepDice2, return the boolean false if the user inputs a String containing 'N' or 'n'. Then, I want to make an if stateent: if the return value is the boolean false, then call the method rollDice2 ( I have not included rollDice2 as it seems irrelevant). ANy insight into this wwould be greatly appreciated!

> ```
> public static boolean keepDice2() {
>             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>             System.out.println("Keep Dice Two?");
>             String keepDice = input.nextLine();
>             boolean answer;
>             if (keepDice.contains("n") || keepDice.contains("N")) {
>                 answer = false;
>                 //here, if the answer contains n or N, then it is a form of "No", so that dice will be re-rolled.   
>             }
>             else {
>                 answer = true;
>             }
>             return answer;
>         }
> public static void (String[] args) {
>     if (keepDice2() == false) {
>             rollDice2();
>                 }
>              }
> ```

Comment: I think all you're missing is the name of the method. Should it be `main`?

Comment: Note that you're instantiating a new `Scanner` on each method call. This will end badly.

Answer (score 4):

`keepDice2()` returns boolean so you don't need to compare it. You also forgot to name the method which is `main`

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    if (!keepDice2()) {
      rollDice2();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you written is correct, but you can achieve the same result with less code.
Everything inside one if statement brackets is a boolean expression. So if you want to write code that will run in case this expression returns true you just write this expression in bracket and that's it, if you want it to run in case it returns fals you just put ! in front of it. 
Eq:

```
if(keepDice2()) {
        rollDice2();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        // put here rest of code you want to run //
        // if keepDice2() returns true           //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////     
    }
    /*if keepDice2 returns false. 
     * But since
     * there are only two possible outcomes
     * you can just use else statement instead
     * if else if with boolean expression in 
     * brackets 
     */
    else if (!keepDice2()) {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        // put here the code you want to run     //
        // if keepDice2() returns false          //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```